# finding sequential patterns of objects in a list with particular properties

Tags: c#, linq, pattern-matching, sequence

I have a class like this:

```
public class TestResults
{
public String TestName {get;set;}
public Int32 StudentID {get;set;}
public Decimal Score {get;set;}
public Date TestTaken {get;set;}
}
```

So some objects mike look like this:

```
test.TestName = "Big Important Test";
test.StudentID = 17;
test.Score = 0.75M;
test.TestTaken = "1/1/2015";

tests.add(test);

test.TestName = "Big Important Test";
test.StudentID = 12;
test.Score = 0.89M;
test.TestTaken = "1/1/2015";

tests.add(test);

test.TestName = "Sneaky Pop Quiz in Chemistry";
test.StudentID = 17;
test.Score = 0.97M;
test.TestTaken = "2/1/2015";

tests.add(test);

test.TestName = "Sneaky Pop Quiz in Chemistry";
test.StudentID = 17;
test.Score = 0.97M;
test.TestTaken = "2/1/2015";

tests.add(test);
```

What I'm trying to determine is something like "For every student, show me students with large jumps in their scores?" [I asked a similar question a while back in the dba.stackexchange.com world](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/96478/54884) and have used the LEAD function, but now I'd like to move the logic into C#.

So a concrete question I'd want to code for would be (as an example):

> Show me students who've jumped from the 60 and 70 percent range to the
>   90 range.

I know I can write a [rat's nest of loops and branching logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7269033/list-sorting-and-pattern-matching), but was wondering if there are any more elegant and more comprehensive ways of identifying sequences of patterns in LINQ / C# land.

I've heard people talk about F#, but have no practical experience with that. Additionally, I think the "pattern matching" I'm talking about is a bit more involved than some of the [simple string-pattern-matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1585085/linq-pattern-matching) I keep running across.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
const decimal differenceLimit = 0.05M;

var studentIdsWithJump = tests.GroupBy (g => g.StudentID)
    .Where(g => g.OrderBy(c => c.Score)
                .GroupAdjacentBy((first, second) => 
                        first.Score + differenceLimit < second.Score
                ).Count() > 1
    )
    .Select(g => g.Key);
```

With the helper method taken [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4682163/563532):

```
public static class LinqExtensions
{
   public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> GroupAdjacentBy<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, T, bool> predicate)
   {
       using (var e = source.GetEnumerator())
       {
           if (e.MoveNext())
           {
               var list = new List<T> { e.Current };
               var pred = e.Current;
               while (e.MoveNext())
               {
                   if (predicate(pred, e.Current))
                   {
                       list.Add(e.Current);
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       yield return list;
                       list = new List<T> { e.Current };
                   }
                   pred = e.Current;
               }
               yield return list;
           }
       }
   }
}
```

This gives you the jumps for all ranges. If you want to narrow it down, you could add a further .Where() for scores > 60, and adjust the `differenceLimit` accordingly

Answer (score 1):

You could use LINQ to get the answer. Here is an example of a way you could do it:

```
var scores = tests.GroupBy(t => t.StudentID)
    .Select(g => new { StudentID = g.Key, Min = g.Min(i => i.Score), Max = g.Max(i => i.Score) })
    .Where(s => s.Max - s.Min > .20M);

foreach(var score in scores)
    Console.WriteLine("Student: {0} Jump: {1}", score.StudentID, score.Max - score.Min);
```

The LINQ statement first groups by `StudentID`. Next it projects the StudentID and Min and Max scores from each group to a new anonymous type. Finally, apply a where condition that only returns items with a "large jump in score". I define "large jump in score" as the difference between max score and min score is greater than .20.

Note: this code will work even when a student has more than 2 scores in the list.

UPDATE:

Since you have updated your post I understand your question better. Here is an updated answer:

```
var scores = tests.GroupBy(t => t.StudentID)
    .Select(g => new { StudentID = g.Key, Min = g.OrderBy(i => i.Score).First(), Max = g.OrderByDescending(i => i.Score).First() })
    .Where(s => (s.Min.Score >= .60M & s.Min.Score < .80M) & s.Max.Score >= .90M & s.Min.TestTaken < s.Max.TestTaken);

foreach(var score in scores)
    Console.WriteLine("Student: {0} Jump: {1}", score.StudentID, score.Max.Score - score.Min.Score);
```

This uses a similar approach, but instead of recording the min and max scores in the anonymous type, I record the `TestResults` instance having the min score and max score. In ther where clause we check that the `TestResults` having the min score is in the 60-80 range. We check that the `TestResults` having the max score is in the 90+ range. Finally, we check that the min score occurred on a date before the max one occurred.